# need SSL for paypal pro?

Tags: php, paypal

if i am using paypal payment method for that should i need SSL for it?
can need SSL for paypal pro?

Comment: Please include the answer from their support staff in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, you're not sending any "private" information to paypal, you're sending the cost of a transaction and some other meta information about the transaction but not any credit card or password information.

If you are using PayFlow Pro Paypal suggestions purchasing of SSL Certificate:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/merchant/CompatibleSSLCertPartner-outside

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PayPal pro, you do need an SSL certificate to be secure.

> **Do I need a Secure Socket Layer (SSL) certificate if I use Website Payments Pro?**
>
> Yes. With Website Payments Pro, your customers enter their credit card information into a form that you host on your server. To protect your customer’s payment information transmitted over the Internet, you will need an SSL certificate on your web server. Learn more about SSL certificates.

[PayPal Pro FAQ](https://www.paypal.com/sg/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-faq-outside#Do_I_need_a_Secure_Socket)